# Windows 7 vs. HP 3050 multifunction, adding scanner device on network IP

Tags: windows-7, networking, scanner

Customer has HP 3050 multifunction. PC is running Windows 7 x64, at IP 10.50.4.x and multifunction is at 10.50.3.1.

Went into devices and printers in Windows 7 control panel, and tried to add device. It sees the printer fine, but isn't detecting the scanner device. Tried and failed to manually add hardware via device manager pane.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with HP Laserjet 3050, but it was on 32-bit, not 64-bit. I could print fine, but Windows Fax and Scan wasn't able to use the scanner. However, I was able to scan using Picasa and VueScan.

I then uninstalled the printer (cum scanner) from Devices and Printers, restarted the computer and let it install the driver again. After that, Windows Fax and Scan started working.